# xcode: ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file.."

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ipad, app-store-connect

I've read numerous other answers for this, but I thought it was worth posting the same question with an addendum..

[image]

I actually solved this exact same problem once before by adding the correct images in my images.xcassets window, however I don't recall how I figured out which boxes to put the image in? How do I link the errors to the correct box?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Cordova? I see you tagged it but have no mention of it?

If you are just to save you some time and effort theres a really good npm plugin that generates all this for you & my xcode picked up all the different sizes automatically. [cordova-icon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-icon).

It's really simple, just have an `icon.png` in your root and run `cordova-icon` in your console. It generates icons for android iOS and windows.